# NodeJS google-cloud/vision: methods does not perform anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Vision in a NodeJS app. Following the [client library example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision#using-the-client-library):

```
console.log('started')
// Performs label detection on the image file
client
  .labelDetection('./mydocument.jpg')
  .then(results => {
    console.log('checked')
    const labels = results[0].labelAnnotations

    console.log('Labels:')
    labels.forEach(label => console.log(label.description))
  }, err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err)
  })
```

Only the 'started' is printed in the console. It does not enter in either success or failure functions. Looking at the Google's Dashboard, it shows the API being consumed (there is a real time graph that updates when my nodejs app runs).
It seems the endpoint does not return anything and there is no timeout. But I can't find anything in docs, Stack Overflow or GitHub issues. Any clue?

Comment: I had a similar issue and I remember it having something to do with the image itself. Have you tried a different image?

Comment: I have tried with 5 different images (png, jpg), none work.

Comment: Well, it’s a shot in the dark but how big are the images?

Comment: I have tried with 100kb, 200kb and 400kb images

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

I verified my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, reinstalled node modules, tried local and bucket images, and it always hangs.

I tried the Python client and got an SSL error.

Finally, I tried the go client and it worked. Curl request demo also works. Annoying that the node library doesnt return an error of some sort.

Comment: I tried running the same code I was having issues with on a fresh install of linux and it started working. 

The laptop I was having issues with was on a Macbook. It must have been something to do with my local env.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to replicate your scenario with version `0.22.1` but everything went well:

1. Installed client library with `npm install --save @google-cloud/vision`
2. Used the code provided in the [quickstart](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/blob/master/samples/quickstart.js) with your `console.log('started')` line.
3. Had the following result:

[image: Vision API Quickstart with Node JS]

Answer (score -2):

your first err => { console.log('ERROR:', err) }), the one right before the .catch is not part of the tutorial.
Try to remove it and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried without it (as in the tutorial) and the problem is the same.